# How can I pass an asterisk to one of the Deno.Command args?

Tags: typescript, shell, deno

I am trying to execute a shell command from Deno where one of the args contains an asterisk. Example:

```
const output = new Deno.Command("cp", { args: ["source/*", "destination"] }).outputSync()
console.error(new TextDecoder().decode(output.stderr))
```

It yields:

```
cp: cannot stat 'source/*': No such file or directory
```

How can I pass an asterisk to one of the `Deno.Command` args?

Comment: You probably need to spawn a shell where the wildcards are implemented. Try: `new Deno.Command("sh", { args: ["-c", "cp source/* destination"] })`

Comment: You are already passing an asterisk, that's the problem. You want to *not* pass an asterisk, and instead pass each filename individually, as in `cp source/file1 source/file2 destination`. When you write `cp source/* destination` in a terminal, the shell will rewrite it into `cp source/file1 source/file2 destination` before executing the command, and if it didn't you'd get the same error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deno uses Rust's [`std:process::Command`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.arg)

> Note that the argument is not passed through a shell, but given
> literally to the program. This means that shell syntax like quotes,
> escaped characters, word splitting, glob patterns, substitution, etc.
> have no effect.

So in order to use `*` you'll need to spawn a shell (`sh`, `bash`) as Glenn Jackman commented.

```
new Deno.Command("sh", { args: ["-c", "cp source/* destination"] }).outputSync()
```